# Sorting json object by value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

I have a json object like below, how do I sort it using date?

```
json = {"date_hash":{"second_bleed":"2014-09-08","sixth_boost":"2014-10-28","first_boost":"2014-06-24","first_bleed":"2014-08-08","fifth_boost":"2014-09-30","fourth_bleed":"2014-11-03","second_boost":"2014-07-15","fourth_boost":"2014-09-02","third_bleed":"2014-10-06","primary_injection":"2014-06-02","third_boost":"2014-08-05"}}
```

I tried doing

```
json['date_hash'].sort(function(a, b){

});
```

Sort is not a function for json?

Comment: It's an object, it has no order and can't be sorted

Comment: looks like you want to print the dates out in some order, so firstly put all the dates in some array and sort it, I suggest while pushing each in some array, you can do the sorting right at that time.

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSON Object. JSON (JavaScript Object *Notation*) is a String. "JSON is a *text format* that is completely language independent ..." See: http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 0):

The date_hash object is a JSON object which doesn't have an order (not sortable).

You should try to use an array:

```
{"date_hash": [
    {"name": "second_bleed", "date": "2014-09-08"},
   ....
   {"name": "sixth_boost", "date": "2014-09-28"}
]}
```

and then you something similar to the function you're using to sort.

```
function (a, b) {
    if (a.date < b.date) {
        return -1;
    } else if (a.date > b.date) {
        return 1;
    };
    return 0;
}
```